# Massive delete based on subquery on WHERE statement. Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, any, string-agg

I need made a subquery with IN statement. Like this (simplify):

```
DELETE
FROM table_1 
WHERE id_table_1 IN (SELECT string_agg(fk_id_table_1::TEXT,',') FROM table_2
```

I need made a massive delete, based on second subquery. The problem is if i use IN statement i must use string_agg to put the id separeted by commas, but id is integer and string_agg need change to text, if i put id_table_1::text IN (...subquery...) it return empty. I try using ANY too and put the id inside a integer array. But it show "ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]". I try use EXISTS too.

Somebody give me some light? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

While you can code a literal values for a `IN` using a comma delimited list, eg `WHERE id_table_1 IN (1,2,3)`, you can't use `string_agg` in the way you're using it. Instead, use a query that returns a single column to create the list of values, like this:

```
DELETE
FROM table_1 
WHERE id_table_1 IN (SELECT fk_id_table_1 FROM table_2)
```

Better, use postgres's [join delete syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM table_1
USING table_2
WHERE table_1.id_table_1 = table_2.fk_id_table_1
```

---

You could use `string_agg()` if you were programatically building a query as a string, but that's not the situation here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the `string_agg`  function in the sub-query (actually, this will return a *single value* of all aggregated ids! hence, no match with any of table 1 ids).

The syntax of the IN operator is: `value IN (value1, value2,...)`,
where the list of values can be a *list of literal values* such as numbers, strings... or a *result of a select statement (sub-query) as `WHERE value IN (SELECT col FROM table_name)`.

So you can fix your query as the following:

```
DELETE
FROM table_1 
WHERE id_table_1 IN (SELECT fk_id_table_1 FROM table_2)
```

And using the `exists` operator:

```
DELETE
FROM table_1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 T2 WHERE T2.fk_id_table_1 = T1.id_table_1)
```

Comment: Yeah i saw later, my fault. Thanks a lot.